# numpy.loadtxt fails to read int in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to make sure that some relatively simple Python 2 modules are compatible with Python 3. I currently have a data file that, for the purposes of an MWE, looks like

```
n
0
```

The following snippet works fine with Python 2.7, which is basically a workaround to get behaviour like `genfromtxt` with `names=True` in both Python 2.7 and 3.5 with the same code.

```
import numpy as np
with open('bad_int.data', 'rb') as f: lines = f.readlines()
data = np.loadtxt(lines[1:2], dtype=[('n', int)])
```

With Python 3.5, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bad_int3.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt(lines[1:2], dtype=[('n',int)])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 938, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'0'"
```

I know there are other ways of loading a file like this but I'm presently bound to slice up the file by lines because it has more than one array. I'm trying to find out what the leading `b` means (binary?) but no luck yet. So how can I read this kind of data in Python 2.7 and 3.5 without getting this error?

**Edit**

I've just noticed that if there's more than one field, everything works fine.  So, for example, if the data changes to

```
n m
0 0
```

and the last line to

```
data = np.loadtxt(lines[1:2], dtype=[('n', int), ('m', int)])
```

then everything works perfectly in Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: are you sure of your input file?

Comment: I just created the MWE example myself using Emacs. I also tried sending it to a file with `echo -e "n\n0" > bad_int.data`.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to automatically infer that the name of the field is `n` from the file but I can do that quite easily. So it suffices just to read the `0`. But the data might not be at the start of the file, nor necessarily the end.

Comment: You're completely right, @Jean-FrançoisFabre! I apologise. Not sure where the `open` went but I've fixed it now.

Comment: Looks like there's something funny about how `loadtxt` handles a single field dtype.  `genfromtxt` works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PY3 you need to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open('data', 'rb') as f: 
     lines = f.readlines()
    data = np.loadtxt(lines[1:2], dtype=[('n',int)])
```

`loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) operate with bytestrings.  So if they open the file themselves they use `rb`.

You could also try:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data', skiprows=1, dtype=[('n',int)])
```

The leading `b` indicates a bytestring.  Py3 strings are unicode by default.

---

```
In [99]: txt=b"""n
    ...: 0
    ...: 1"""
In [100]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines()[1:], dtype=int)
Out[100]: array([0, 1])
```

but with your dtype

```
In [101]: dt=np.dtype([('n',int)])
In [102]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines()[1:], dtype=dt)
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'0'"
```

but this works:

```
In [103]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines()[1:], dtype=dt)
Out[103]: 
array([(0,), (1,)], 
      dtype=[('n', '<i4')])
```

Or let `genfromtxt` create the dtype:

```
In [105]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, names=True)
Out[105]: 
array([(0,), (1,)], 
      dtype=[('n', '<i4')])
```

So there's something about how `loadtxt` is treating the `dtype` that is giving problems.  I haven't seen this before.  But then I haven't seen many cases of loading just one column.

Comment: The first part of your solution (changing `r` to `rb`) doesn't work for me. In fact, it doesn't seem to change anything. I'd like to be able to use something more like your second suggestion but my actual data isn't necessarily at the start or end of the file.

Comment: Your additions indirectly made me find out why I was getting errors using `genfromtxt` on a list of lines, so I'm basically now using that solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I think "open" is missing just after the "with"